# How to change MarkUpSafe version in virtual environment?

Tags: python, flask, grpc

I am trying to make an application using python and gRPC as shown in this article - [link](https://realpython.com/python-microservices-grpc/)

I am able to run the app successfully on my terminal but to run with a frontend I need to run it as a flask app, [codebase](https://github.com/realpython/materials/tree/master/python-microservices-with-grpc). And I am doing all this in a virtual environment.

when I run my flask command `FLASK_APP=marketplace.py flask run`

This is the error I get

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (/Users/alex/Desktop/coding/virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/markupsafe/__init__.py)
```

On researching about this error I found this [link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/3661) - it basically tells us that currently I am using a higher version of MarkUpSafe library than required.

So I did `pip freeze --local`  inside the virtualenv and got MarkUpSafe version to be `MarkupSafe==2.1.0`

I think if I change the version of this library from 2.1.0 to 2.0.1 then the flask app might run.

How can I change this library's version from the terminal?

PS: If you think changing the version of the library won't help in running the flask app, please let me know what else can I try in this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If downgrading will solve the issue for you try the following code inside your virtual environment.

`pip install MarkupSafe==2.0.1`

Comment: Yes it did solve my issue! thank you.

Comment: I had Flask app on python 3.7 and your solution solved my problem.